# Changing the range of the histogram in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

Here is a program that displays the histogram of the list below:

```
costlist = [48, 43, 51, 36, 6, 25, 51, 71,
                59, 70, 78, 36, 18, 84, 5, 9, 13,
                90, 71, 39, 80, 2, 69, 48, 21,
                66, 10, 37, 89, 20, 27, 7, 12,
                314, 83, 39, 31, 36, 56, 60,
                62, 23, 70, 51, 46, 40, 100,
                29, 30, 59, 37, 94, 99, 20, 88,
                10, 36, 42, 14, 24, 33, 60, 370,
                2, 30, 32, 85, 14, 52, 47, 16,
                25, 21, 29, 78, 83, 310, 43, 62,
                54, 83, 74, 52, 65, 82, 44, 94,
                83, 21, 36, 41, 67, 81, 32, 28,
                87, 62, 12]
```

the Result is:

```
 Element Value  Histogram
    0-9     6
  10-19     9
  20-29    13
  30-39    15
  40-49    10
  50-59     9
  60-69     9
  70-79     7
  80-89    12
  90-99     4
```

However, I want it to output the number of items in each range:

```
Range   Value    Histogram
1 - 19   4       ****
20 - 29  5       *****
30 - 39  0
40 - 49  0
50 - 59  0
60 - 69  5       *****
70 - 79  10      **********
80 - 89  0
90 - 99  0
100+     3       ***
```

Here is my code:

```
def production_cost():
    costlist = [48, 43, 51, 36, 6, 25, 51, 71,
                59, 70, 78, 36, 18, 84, 5, 9, 13,
                90, 71, 39, 80, 2, 69, 48, 21,
                66, 10, 37, 89, 20, 27, 7, 12,
                314, 83, 39, 31, 36, 56, 60,
                62, 23, 70, 51, 46, 40, 100,
                29, 30, 59, 37, 94, 99, 20, 88,
                10, 36, 42, 14, 24, 33, 60, 370,
                2, 30, 32, 85, 14, 52, 47, 16,
                25, 21, 29, 78, 83, 310, 43, 62,
                54, 83, 74, 52, 65, 82, 44, 94,
                83, 21, 36, 41, 67, 81, 32, 28,
                87, 62, 12]
    return costlist
def count_scores(scores, low, high):
    if
    return len([x for x in scores if x >= low and x <= high])
def histogram(costlist):
    d = {'%d-%d'%(x, x + 9):
         count_scores(costlist, x, x + 9) for x in range(0, 100, 10)}
    for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
        print ('%7s %5d'%(k,v))
def main():
    costlist = production_cost()
    print("%7s %5s %10s" %("Element", "Value", "Histogram"))
    histogram(costlist)

main()
```

My code runs correctly, except it has no asterisks and the ranges are missing something. The `0-9` and `10-19` should be combined, and there should be an added one for the last range which is `100+`.

EDIT: Here are the constraints.

- Do not use if statements
- Use at least one def not including main
- No imports

Comment: http://repl.it/9Ih just made this

Comment: It has if statements tho @rafaeldefazio

Comment: http://repl.it/9Zl - well, it works hahahahha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to map each item of `costlist` into its proper histogram bin, using data "similar" to what `prices` is supposed to return.  I say "similar" because e.g for `a` it computes `1 - 19`, one minus nineteen, which is a useless `-18`, and so forth.

So, first, change `prices` to return something **useful** instead of those useless differences, e.g:

```
def prices():
    return [1] + list(range(20, 110, 10))
```

that list the list of lower bounds for the bins (each upper bound is of course given by the next bin's lower bound).  I'm calling `list` on `range` since you're using Python 3 (in Python 2 you could elide `list).

Simplest way to use these data is to build a `dict` mapping each integer in range to its bin number (this way looking for the bin given an integer will be nearly instantaneous, rather than take some time with other representations):

```
p = prices()
int2bin = {}
for i in range(1, len(p)):
    for j in range(p[i-1], p[i]):
        int2bin[j] = i - 1
lastbin = len(p) - 1
```

Now it's trivial to find the bin for each integer, and thus, similarly trivial to count how many integers fall in each given bin:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(
    int2bin.get(i, lastbin)
    for i in costlist)
```

Added: the OP just commented (though the Q isn't edited accordingly) that module `collections` is undesired (such constraints should of course always be  spelled out clearly and explicitly in the question in the first place!) apparently because this is a school exercise.

So, if you need to re-implement `collections.Counter` by hand, of course you can do that...:

```
c = {}
for i in costlist:
    thebin = int2bin.get(i, lastbin)
    if thebin in c:
        c[thebin] += 1
    else:
        c[thebin] = 1
```

There -- six statements (counting if/else as one) instead of one (plus the import), and we have reimplemented `collections.Counter` for this special case.  Personally I think it's best and wisest to use appropriately high levels of abstraction -- though of course it's also smart to understand what, conceptually, lies beneath them.

But the concept of **counting** comes so naturally to human beings (and in any case has been drilled into students ever since first grade) that I don't think it's necessary to repeat it again in this case!

"If there are already things in the bin and you put another one there, then add one to the bin's count; if there were no things in the bin yet, so you're putting the first think in the bin, then start the bin's count at one" -- is it **truly** worthwhile to ask high schoolers to sit through such drills **again**?!

Ah well, I'm not trained as a teacher, so I guess I won't rant about how utterly **bored** I was by exactly such useless repetitions of long-absorbed concepts throughout **my** time in school -- and I heard exactly the same from my children back when **they** were in school:-).

Back to actually-fun stuff...:

Now, only the printing task remains, after a slightly different header (the one you say you want):

```
print("%7s %5s %10s" %("Range", "Value", "Histogram"))
```

You can just loop over the bins:

```
for i, lo in enumerate(p):
    if i + 1 < len(p):
        rng = '%d-%d' % (lo, p[i+1]-1)
    else:
        rng = '%d+' % lo
    val = c[i]
    stars = '*' * val
    print("%7s %5s %-10s" %(rng, val, stars))
```

Putting it all together, you'll see the result:

```
  Range Value  Histogram
   1-19    15 ***************
  20-29    13 *************
  30-39    15 ***************
  40-49    10 **********
  50-59     9 ********* 
  60-69     9 ********* 
  70-79     7 *******   
  80-89    12 ************
  90-99     4 ****      
   100+     4 ****
```

Which seems to be what you're asking for.

There are of course alternatives (e.g, use something else than a `dict` to do the mapping from integer to bin number) and things that may require explanation depending on your Python skills, so, feel free to ask further!

Added: so here are the latest extra constraints the OP's been piling up on this Q:
- No if statements
- Use at least one def not including main
- No imports

The `def` is already there in `prices`, and there are no `import`s now (in the non-Counter version).  "No `if` statements" is really ridiculous (on a par with having to stand on just the left foot while coding!-) but fortunately Python offers tricks to play around such absurdities.

So to build the counter, let's use:

```
def counter(costlist):
    c = {}
    for i in costlist:
        thebin = int2bin.get(i, lastbin)
        try:
            c[thebin] += 1
        except KeyError:
            c[thebin] = 1
```

this is the first `if`-removing trick: instead of the more spontaneous check whether `thebin` has already been put in the `dict` `c`, here we assume it has, and handle the exception produced when it hadn't been.  This is actually a well-recognized Python idiom, which I promoted (even before I wrote "Python in a Nutshell", where I pounded on it:-) as "It's easier to ask forgiveness than permission", borrowing Commodore Hopper's great motto (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZDWveIdqjY for my talk on the subject).

And we'll use **exactly** the same trick to remove the *other* `if`, simply rephrasing the snippet:

```
for i, lo in enumerate(p):
    if i + 1 < len(p):
        rng = '%d-%d' % (lo, p[i+1]-1)
    else:
        rng = '%d+' % lo
```

with:

```
for i, lo in enumerate(p):
    try:
        rng = '%d-%d' % (lo, p[i+1]-1)
    except IndexError:
        rng = '%d+' % lo
```

Here, it works because, if `(i + 1)` is **not** `< len(p)` as originally checked by the normal `if`, the indexing `p[i+1]` will raise an `IndexError`, and the `except` clause deals with that!

Now if I assess the OP correctly, I have two predictions: (A) this will not be sufficient (more constraints will spring from nothingness, such as "no try/except statements"!-) and (B) the OP will *still* not accept this answer and open another question with **all** the constraints.  I suspect I'm spot-on re (A) because I can't imagine a teacher willing to accept `try/except` if they forbid the much-simpler `if`; I can just hope I'm wrong on (B), i.e that the OP will realize they won't get one more bit of time and energy out of me until and unless they accept this question, and thereby reluctantly click on that checkmark outline and ask another...:-)

Comment: could there possibly be a way without `counter` and `collections`? This is a   high school program, so you shouldn't overthink it.

Comment: Sure!  You just need to do more work yourself to reproduce what `collections.Counter` does for you.  Note that using the tools the language gives you is exactly the opposite of "overthinking it": being forced to reproduce those tools from lower-abstraction ones is what requires more thinking (which is why it's OK for teaching purposes I guess, but those constraints should always be **clearly spelled out in the question** so please edit the Q to add the constraints!).  Anyway, editing now.

Comment: This is because we haven't learned Counter yet, so it would be odd to have it in the program

Comment: Then I suggest refactoring the alternative code I gave into a `def counter` function accepting the sequence and returning the `dict` of counts -- so later it can be transparently replaced with `collections.Counter`, and meanwhile you can easily de-emphasize its explanation since "it's just counting" (in fact I'd hope you'd teach counting before more advanced stuff such as histograms:-).  Come to think of it, `int2bin.get(i, lastbin)` should also be refactored into a named function, for different reasons (clarity and ease of exploring alternatives).  Would work better as a class, but, ah well!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however there is now a new problem in my code. Please see the edits.

Comment: @asdfmovie, so I'll edit to satisfy the constraints and expect you still **won't** accept (as you already should have by common decency and SO etiquette, since I **did** fix the question you originally posed, so you should have accepted this A and posted another Q -- instead, you keep piling up extra constraints on this single one leaving me at 0, **very** rude).  Ah well, I'll spend even **more** time on this for 0 rep, but only this last once -- after that I will do no further followup.

Comment: @asdfmovie, your behavior was a nasty violation of OS etiquette (and of obvious, plain, general common courtesy, too).  My answer was just as good when you un-accepted it as it had been when you first accepted it -- so taking away the accept was rude and unwarranted.  Rather, you should obviously have opened **another** question, with all relevant constraints, while leaving this answer as accepted.

Comment: I wanted to open a new question, however SO made me question limited for only one question (this one) which had an even score. And sorry for my crappy behavior earlier, I reaccepted it.

Comment: But thank you, now my problem is totally and completely solved, and we can move on.

Comment: By the way, I also read your book (Python in a Nutshell), and it was very well written. I enjoyed it very much, and it helped me understand some other concepts.

Comment: @asdfmovie glad you liked the Nutshell, working on a 3rd ed now, but it will be a long time coming (figure a year or so).

Comment: Take your time... I will be waiting :)